# How to define choices instead of tasks and print answers at the end

Tags: exsheets, tasks, auto-multiple-choice

I am trying to write some questions which are of objective or multiple choice format. The **tasks** package does the job except for two things:

> 1. Instead of \begin{tasks} and \task I want to write \begin{choices} and \choice;
> 2. I want to include and option \correctchoice and print all the answers et the end.

I tried reading the documentations but I am not able to do this. Please help me.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
    Which one of the entries does not fit with the others?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task mercury
        \task iron
        \task lead
        \task zinc
    \end{tasks}
\end{question}
\settasks{
    counter-format=(tsk[a]),
    label-width=4ex
}
\begin{question}
    What is a function?
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task A dancing electron
        \task A dancing proton
        \task A dancing neutron
        \task A Dixie Dancing Duck
    \end{tasks}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Now (more than two years after the question was posted) it is reasonably easy with `exsheets`' successor `xsim` to achieve what you want. The example below defines an environment `choices` like this:

```
\NewTasksEnvironment[
  label = (\alph*) ,
  label-width = 16pt
]{choices}[\choice]
```

Then an exercise property `answer` is defined and a command which saves the answer:

```
\DeclareExerciseProperty{answer}    
\newcommand*\answer[1]{%
  \SetExpandedExerciseProperty{answer}{ (\alph{task}) \unexpanded{#1}}%
 #1%
}
```

At last a command is defined which retrieves the answers:

```
\newcommand*\getanswers{%
  \def\betweenanswers{\def\betweenanswers{\hspace{2em}}}%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByID{%
    \betweenanswers##3\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{answer}%
  }%
}
```

This is then used like this – the syntax is not exactly as wanted but quite close:

```
\begin{exercise}
  Which one of the entries does not fit with the others?
  \begin{choices}(4)
    \choice mercury
    \choice iron
    \choice \answer{lead}
    \choice zinc
  \end{choices}
\end{exercise}
```

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-files]{xsim}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewTasksEnvironment[
  label = (\alph*) ,
  label-width = 16pt
]{choices}[\choice]

\DeclareExerciseProperty{answer}    
\newcommand*\answer[1]{%
  \SetExpandedExerciseProperty{answer}{ (\alph{task}) \unexpanded{#1}}%
 #1%
}

\newcommand*\getanswers{%
  \def\betweenanswers{\def\betweenanswers{\hspace{2em}}}%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByID{%
    \betweenanswers##3\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{answer}%
  }%
}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name = Question ,
  exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}.
}

\begin{document}

\section{Questions}
\begin{exercise}
  Which one of the entries does not fit with the others?
  \begin{choices}(4)
    \choice mercury
    \choice iron
    \choice \answer{lead}
    \choice zinc
  \end{choices}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
  Which one of the entries does not fit with the others?
  \begin{choices}(4)
    \choice argon
    \choice \answer{hydrogen}
    \choice neon
    \choice helium
  \end{choices}
\end{exercise}

\section{Answers}
\getanswers

\end{document}
```